# Why does this Mongo query return nothing when inside a loop, but the body of the loop works?

Tags: mongodb

If I run the following query in the mongo shell all I get is a bunch of empty arrays printed out to the screen:

```
for (c in collections) {printjson(db.getCollection(c).find().limit(1).toArray())  }
```

where `collections` is a list of all the collections in the current `db`. But if I run just say:

```
printjson(db.getCollection(collections[0]).find().limit(1).toArray())
```

I get a json document printed out to the screen.

Why am I seeing this behavior in the mongo shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for...in` loop, `c` is the current index of `collections`, not the array element.

So you'd need to change that to be:

```javascript
for (c in collections) { printjson(db.getCollection(collections[c]).find().limit(1).toArray())  }
```